# Is angular-data a dependency of angular-cache or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I don't know why I'm having such a hard time setting up `angular-cache`. As per the [docs](http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/documentation/api/angular-cache/angular-cache): `Angular-cache is a dependency of angular-data and must be loaded before angular-data if you are using angular-data.` Okay, that's cool, but what if I don't care about `angular-data` and just want to use `angular-cache`?

The docs also say: `ur Angular app must depend on the module "angular-data.DSCacheFactory" in order to use angular-cache`

So my question is: do I need both or can I somehow just use `angular-cache`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular-data.DSCacheFactory` is the new name of what used to be called `angular-cache`.

It is not dependent upon any packages other than Angular itself.